# Attempting to use CTE in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I know this isn't the best way to achieve this, but I'm just playing around with things as I continue to learn. I used a CTE to join two tables and now I'd like to aggregate off of the temporary table.

I keep receiving the following error in various ways, seems like BQ is telling me that it doesn't recognize the values in the second statement:

> Name accounts not found inside accounts_Opps at [15:22]

Here's the query:

```
WITH accounts_Opps AS (
  SELECT  Accounts.Id, Accounts.name,  
          Accounts.sales_territory_c, 
          Accounts.cs_stage_c,
          opportunities.account_Id,
          opportunities.name,
          opportunities.rep_projected_arr_c,
          opportunities.stage_name
  FROM `salesforce.account` AS Accounts
  LEFT JOIN `salesforce.opportunity` AS Opportunities
  ON Accounts.id = Opportunities.account_id
  WHERE Opportunities.account_Id IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT accounts_Opps.accounts.name, count(accounts_opps.opportunities.rep_projected_arr_c)
FROM accounts_Opps
GROUP BY accounts_Opps.accounts.name
```

Again, although I know this isn't the best way to achieve this, I'm just playing with different approaches and I'm wondering if this approach would work and if so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure `accounts_Opps.accounts.name` is correct. It should be `accounts_Opps.name` you can't refer to the table only the table alias + column name. I'm only human though, so what should i know

Comment: Columns coming out of the CTE are exposed by whatever you name them in the `select`. I nothing gained from this wrapping in your query though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with duplicate names, one from Accounts and another from Opportunities, which is not feasible. Columns that have identical names can be differentiated by assigning aliases.

As pointed out in the comments by @shawnt00, the columns that come out of the CTE are recognized by their original name or by the alias assigned in the select statement.

```
WITH accounts_Opps AS (
  SELECT  Accounts.Id, 
          Accounts.name as account_name,  
          Accounts.sales_territory_c, 
          Accounts.cs_stage_c,
          opportunities.name as opportunity_name,
          opportunities.rep_projected_arr_c,
          opportunities.stage_name
  FROM `account` AS Accounts
  LEFT JOIN `opportunity` AS opportunities
  ON Accounts.id = opportunities.account_id
  WHERE opportunities.account_Id IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT account_name, count(rep_projected_arr_c)
FROM accounts_Opps
GROUP BY account_name
```

Comment: Also, like all subqueries, the table alias `Accounts` is stripped out of the column name in the CTE's result set.  This results in two columns named `name`, as @SelVazi says.  Also, I don't believe CTEs improve the readability of your SQL;  they interrupt the flow when you are decoding someone else's logic, causing you to have to look away up to the top and then remember your place when you return.  I recommend  using CTE's only for what they were meant: recursive Selects or cases where you use the same subquery twice.

Comment: There are plenty of other users, @ChrisMaurer . Pre-aggregation, nesting of (window) functions (which can't normally be), and sometimes breaking down the query into distinct parts *is* easier. I agree that here, however, the use of the CTE has no benefit.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the thorough explanations. SelVazi's solution worked perfectly and definitely helped me (and hopefully) other's understand the nature of CTE's a bit more. Appreciate the feedback.